# How to upload image from subdomain folder to folder inside public_html using codeigniter file upload?

Tags: php, codeigniter, path

I have a subdomain folder 'test.in' runing in codeigniter which is outside public_html folder. Inside public_html folder, I have another codeigniter project that has a folder "uploads". Now I want to upload file from subdomain folder "test.in" to the "uploads" folder inside public_html.
This is my file upload code within a helper function.

```
function do_upload($img){
      $files = $_FILES[$img];
      $ci = & get_instance();
      $ci->load->library('upload');
      $config['upload_path'] = '../uploads/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
      $_FILES[$img]['name'] = time().'_'.$files['name'];
      $filename=$_FILES[$img]['name'];
      $_FILES[$img]['type'] = $files['type'];
      $_FILES[$img]['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'];
      $_FILES[$img]['error'] = $files['error'];
      $_FILES[$img]['size'] = $files['size'];
      $ci->upload->initialize($config);
      if ($ci->upload->do_upload($img))
      {
        $prod_img = array('upload_data' => $ci->upload->data());
      }
      else
      {
      }
      return $filename;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Your controller give you back any error? Are you sure that '../uploads/' is the right path of the directory you want to use? Have you also check writing permission on this directory (if under Linux)?

Comment: Yes the error is showing like "<p>The upload path does not appear to be valid.</p>". But what is the correct way to provide the path name for uploading file from subdomain(outside public_html folder) to main domain (inside public_html folder)?

Comment: You have just receive an answer; it can be right, if your directory tree is equal. You can add any ../ you need to "traversal up" the directory tree, it depend how many level you must go back...

Comment: are you on a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your folder structure

```
test.in
---application
---...... (so on)
public_html
---application
---.......( so on)
---uploads
```

Try setting following

```
$config['upload_path'] = './../public_html/uploads/';
```

Reference : [File Uploading Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#id5)